# how to fix textlabel shadow layout

Tags: ios, swift

I refer to [this link](http://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/uicollectionview-using-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-sticky-rows-and-columns) implement **uicollectionview which horizontal and vertical scrolling sticky rows and columns**, it looks like below.

[image]

and I want to add shadow to each textlabel which in first column, like below code.

```
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 2
```

but when I continue scroll this uicollection view, I find some layout error happend :(

[image]

I don't know how to fix it, any ideas?

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Collectionview is reusing its cell that already has added shadow

Then you have to all a method in cellAtIndexPathAtindex method

```
if firstcolummn
{
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 2

}
else
{

cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 0


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 2
```

Add these line in `prepareForReuse()` method in your cell.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are giving shadow to the cell and not the textlabel.

```
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 2
```

The above code will give shadow to cell and not textLabel. You can apply shadow to textLabel like

```
cell.textLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 2
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but It can't work well, layout error also appear :(

Comment: I mean it also works as my above statement. messy layout :(